# Cython memoryview transpose: Typeerror

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, cython, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to develop a small Convolutional Neural Network framework with python.
The code for the convolutional node already works (slowly) and I would like to speed it up.
The hotspots are the loops where the convolutional filter is moved across the image. I chose to use cython to speed up those loops.

The obvious small annotations, cdef for all local variables and removing boundscheck, shaved hardly 10% off of my runtime. That seemed strange to me, based on what I read online, cython should already be able to do its magic.

Unfortunately the code is inside a class and relies heavily on the properties of that class. I decided to convert it into a cdef class. This means that all class attributes have to be declared with cdef. Apparently cython doesn't support numpy arrays, so I declared all numpy arrays as `double[:,:,...]`

So far the code worked fine, all unittests passing. Now the compilation to .pyd (I'm working under windows) still works. But running the code creates a Typeerror:

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Here is some code. This is the entire forward method of my convolutional node, which might be too much and not easily readable. You probably only need the very last line. That's were the error happens:

```
    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.nonecheck(False)
    def forward(self):

        # im2col: x -> in_cols
        # padding
        cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=4] x_padded = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.in_colors, self.in_width + self.padding*2, self.in_height + self.padding*2))
        if self.padding>0:
            x_padded[:, :, self.padding:self.in_width+self.padding, self.padding:self.in_height+self.padding] = self.x
        else:
            x_padded[:]=self.x

        # allocating new field
        cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=4] rec_fields = np.empty((self.filter_size**2* self.in_colors, self.batch_size, self.out_width, self.out_height))

        # copying receptive fields
        cdef int w,h
        for w, h in np.ndindex((self.out_width, self.out_height)):
            rec_fields[:, :, w, h] = x_padded[:, :, w*self.stride:w*self.stride + self.filter_size, h*self.stride:h*self.stride + self.filter_size] \
                .reshape((self.batch_size, self.filter_size**2* self.in_colors)) \
                .T

        self.in_cols = rec_fields.reshape((self.filter_size**2 * self.in_colors, self.batch_size * self.out_width * self.out_height))

        # linear node: in_cols -> out_cols
        cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] out_cols=np.dot(self.W,self.in_cols)+self.b

        # col2im: out_cols -> out_image -> y
        cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=4] out_image = out_cols.reshape((self.out_colors, self.batch_size, self.out_width, self.out_height))
        self.y[:] = out_image.transpose(1, 0, 2, 3)
```

This last call to transpose is marked in the exception. I can't explain this. Do memoryviews behave differently when transposed ?

UPDATE:

I'm sure that the dimensions are defined correctly. If there is a dimension mismatch, it produces a different runtime error. Can't check right now, but it was something like "got 4-dim, expected 2-dim". 
I've got to say that I'm extremely impressed by the type system of cython. This kind of runtime type information in a python exception is rather useful.
Sadly it doesn't explain why the transpose above fails.

UPDATE:

There's some complication with the arrays: They must not be overwritten, only be used as references.

A little difficult to explain:
At the core of the neural network is a loop which calls the method forward() on all nodes in the network consecutively.

```
for node in self.nodes:
    node.forward()
```

In this method the node looks at its input data, makes some computations and writes to its output. It relies on the fact that the input already contains the correct data.

For the setup of my network I store the nodes in the right order. And I connect them manually.

```
node2.x=node1.y
```

Now if I write

```
self.y[:]= data
```

in the forward method of node1, node2 automatically has the correct input.
This requires careful programming: the forward methods must be called in the right order and the output must never be overwritten, only written to.

The alternative would be a huge structure where I store the output of each node and pass this data around. That would create lots of boilerplate code and mess up the forward and backward pass.

UPDATE:

the last few lines in forward now look like this:

```
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=4] out_image = out_cols.reshape((self.out_colors, self.batch_size, self.out_width, self.out_height))
        cdef double[:,:,:,:] temp
        temp=out_image.transpose(1,0,2,3)
        self.y[...] = temp
```

The assignment to temp fails with the same TypeError message.

Comment: One option to avoid this would be not to type the class attributes (e.g `cdef object y`). That way they can be of any type. You might lose a small amount of speed but you could get some of it back by assigning to a typed local variable before use.

Comment: But if you wanted to keep them as memoryviews, I think you just need to change your assignment syntax to match the number of dimensions: `self.y[:,:,:,:] = ...`

Comment: The assignments have the correct number of dimensions. It's always either 4 dim (batch_size, features, width, height) or 2 dim (filter_size**2 * features, batch_size*width*height)

Comment: If the dimensions are wrong, there is a runtime error, too. but it says explicitly that the dimensions don't match. I had that error too ...

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood what you said. I thought you meant declarations. I'll try to update the assignment

Comment: Interesting idea, since at other places, I've used  [:,:,:,:]. Sometimes there is slicing involved and I wanted to emphasize that in those cases, there is no slicing. Assignments with [:,:,:,:] didn't fail. Can't wait to try that out

Comment: Not sure I got it quite right - ndarray to memoryview slicing assignment doesn't seem to work. See answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.y[...] = some_array
# or equivalently self.y[:,:,:,:] = some_array
```

does a copy of `some_array` into `self.y`, which must already be initialised to the right size. It also only seems to work if `some_array` is already a memoryview (which doesn't hugely make sense to me, but this seems to be the case).

(`self.y[:] = some_array` only works for 1D arrays)

If you just want make `self.y` "look at" a numpy array you just want to do

```
self.y = some_array
# in your case:
# self.y = out_image.transpose(1, 0, 2, 3)
```

The chances are that the this is fine for your purposes!

---

If you're particularly keen on making a copy (possibly if you've taken a C pointer to `self.y` or something like that) then you have to force `some_array` to be a memoryview. You'd do something like

```
cdef double[:,:,:,:] temporary_view_of_transpose

# temporary_view_of_transpose now "looks at" the memory allocated by transpose
# no square brackets!
temporary_view_of_transpose = out_image.transpose(1, 0, 2, 3)

# data is copied from temporary_view_of_transpose to self.y
self.y[...] = temporary_view_of_transpose # (remembering that self.y must be the correct shape before this assignment).
```

---

I agree the error message seen is unhelpful!

---

**Edit:** The following is minimum complete example that works for me (Cython 0.24, Python 3.5.1, Linux - I can't easily test on Anaconda) At this stage I'm not clear what's different in your code.

```
# memview.pyx
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

cdef class MemviewClass:
    cdef double[:,:,:,:] y

    def __init__(self):
        self.y = np.zeros((2,3,4,5))

    def do_something(self):
        cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t,ndim=4] out_image = np.ones((3,2,4,5))
        cdef double[:,:,:,:] temp
        temp = out_image.transpose(1,0,2,3)
        self.y[...] = temp

    def print_y(self):
        # just to check it gets changed
        print(np.asarray(self.y))
```

and test_script.py to show it works:

```
# use pyximport for ease of testing
import numpy
import pyximport; pyximport.install(setup_args=dict(include_dirs=numpy.get_include()))

import memview

a = memview.MemviewClass()
a.print_y() # prints a big array of 0s
a.do_something()
a.print_y() # prints a big array of 1s
```

Comment: That's strange. I would have expected this intermediate step to be exactly the same as the assignment to self.y . After all self.y is a memoryview of 4 dimensions. And temporaryview is a memoryview of 4 dimensions. Why does one assignment fail and the other work ? It seems like the problem is just moved somewhere else.  Thanks for the tip, I'll try that as soon as I get home.

Comment: As expected: The code now fails at the assignment to temporary_view_of_transpose. Same error message "TypeError: only length 1 arrays can be converted to python scalars". Does that work for you ? I'm using python 3.5 with the anaconda distribution and cython 0.24

Comment: Yes - using the final block of code works as written (Cython 0.24). I've edited it slightly to make it slightly clearer what's happening. You've got to be clear on the difference between `mview = something` (`mview` is now set to look at the memory held by something) vs `mview[...] = something` (the data in the memory looked at by `something` is copied into the memory looked at by `mview`, and they both have to be memoryviews)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I've updated the question with the exact code that fails.

Comment: I've added a complete working example which I think covers a simplified version of what you're trying to do. At this case I don't know what isn't working for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. I'm at a loss, why it didn't the first time I tried. My guess is that I messed up the re-compilation. That would be embarrassing. Unfortunately this solution creates a new error. In the forward pass in my network I have to transpose outcols to get y. In the backward pass, it's exactly inverted. And memoryviews don't seem to have a transpose method (only .T) . And I can't cast the memoryview to ndarray.... Well, I've accepted your answer, since it is the perfect answer to my question.

Comment: I've created a question for the new problem. You seem to be an expert on cython, would you care to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226813/cython-transpose-a-memoryview